# PosgtreSQL - update column if its value equals to DEFAULT value

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a PostgreSQL table with default values for columns that were not specified in the insert query.
How can I run query to update column value if its current value is equal to DEFAULT?

In MySQL, I have

```
UPDATE t SET foo = 'foo' WHERE foo = DEFAULT(foo);
```

but it is not working in PosgtreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the default value of a column from the `column_default` column of `information_schema.columns`.

For columns defined as `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` this value is returned as `'somevalue'::character varying` or `'somevalue'::bpchar` respectively, so you must take the part before `::` and trim the single quotes:

```
UPDATE t
SET foo = 'new value'
WHERE foo = (
  SELECT TRIM('''' FROM SPLIT_PART(column_default, '::', 1))
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE table_name = 't' AND column_name = 'foo'
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c2e63be2c71dc6ea8cb0166a58a2baf).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that in PostgreSQL, and I cannot imagine how such a feature could work at all.

Imagine the column is defined as

```
foo timestamp DEFAULT localtimestamp
```

How could you tell if the timestamp that has been inserted happened to be the default value or not?